# Отправка открытого файла дважды

Tags: python, requests

Скрипт открывает файл и отправляет его два раза. Проблема в том, что файл отправляется только в первом запросе, второй запрос уходит без файла. Если убрать закомментированные строки, то во втором запросе файл отправляется корректно. Что происходит с переменной img_file после первого запроса, почему не получается использовать её второй раз?

```
import requests  

img_path = '9.jpg'
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'

img_file = open(img_path, 'rb')

files = {'f1': img_file}
response = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
print(response.text)
response.close()
#img_file.close()

#img_file = open(img_path, 'rb')
files = {'f2': img_file}
response = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
print(response.text)
response.close()

img_file.close()
```

Comment: Переменная `img_file` представляет открытый файловый объект. После первого запроса файловый указатель перемещается в конец файла, поэтому при попытке повторно отправить файл, данные не будут переданы, так как файловый объект уже достиг конца файла. Попробуйте img_file.seek(0), после отправки первoго запроса.

Comment: Сергей, благодарю. Действительно img_file.seek(0) помог.